# If $f\to \infty$ along a sequence, then $f'\to \infty$ along a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-writing, continuity

Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function. Assume that exists a sequence, ${x_n}\subset(a,b)$ with $x_n\rightarrow b$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$. I need to prove that exists a sequence ${y_n}\subset(a,b)$, with $y_n \rightarrow b$, and $f'(y_n)\rightarrow\infty$.

What we know about $x_n$ implies that $x=b$ is an essential discontinuity point of $f$.  I totally understand why the derivative would go to infinity, conceptually, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it.

Comment: I think the OP means that for this given $f$ we have this property.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht This is a question from an exam. The information about $x_n$ was given as part of the question.

Comment: If there is no such sequence $y_n$ then $f'$ is bounded above near $b.$

Comment: You should change "We know" to "Assume that"

Comment: @zhw. Done, thanks

Comment: @zhw. I did that and proved uniform continuity on the interval, implying finite limits at  a and b in contradiction. Thanks for the tip (:

Comment: Are you sure about uniform continuity? I'm not sure how that follows. Also, you should be clear that $b<\infty$ here.

Comment: How about to take a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $x_{n_k} > 2^k + x_{n_{k-1}}$ and use the mean value theorem on the interval $[x_{n_{k-1}}, x_{n_k}]$ to get a sequence $c_k$?

Answer (score 2):

I assume $b<\infty,$ otherwise the result fails. Since $f(x_n)\to \infty,$ we can pass to a strictly increasing subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that

$$\tag 1 f(x_{n_{k+1}}) - f(x_{n_{k}}) > 1\,\text { for all } k.$$

By the MVT there are points $y_k \in (x_{n_{k}},x_{n_{k+1}})$ such that the left side of $(1)$ equals

$$\tag 2 f'(y_k)(x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_{k}})$$

for all $k.$ Note that $y_k\to b.$ Since $x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_{k}}\to 0$ and $(2)>1,$ we must have $f'(y_k) \to \infty$ as desired.

Comment: thanks, this works. If you have a moment please have a look at the proof I wrote below, I'd be happy to know what you think

Answer (score 0):

Here'e the proof I came up with.

Assume there does not exist a sequence as such in $(a,b)$, hence, there exists some $M>0$ such that $\forall x\in(a,b): |f'(x)|<M $. Let there be some $\alpha, \beta \in (a,b)$. $f$ is differentiable on $(\alpha, \beta)$ so it's continuous on $[\alpha,\beta]$ and the mean value theorem applies, so: $$\exists \gamma \in (\alpha, \beta): |f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|=|f'(\gamma)||\alpha-\beta|<M|\alpha -\beta|$$ Let there be some $\epsilon>0$. Set $\delta=\epsilon/M$. It follows that for every $\alpha, \beta \in (a,b)$, if $|\alpha-\beta|<\delta$, then $$|f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|<M|\alpha -\beta|<M\cdot \epsilon/M=\epsilon$$ This means f is uniform continuous on (a,b), and as such, it has finite limits at the ends of a bounded interval, which contradicts the assumption that $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow b$.

Comment: No, it does not follow that $|f'(x)| < M.$ First of all, there's no information about what's happening near $a.$ Second, why should $f'$ be bounded below near $b?$ (Answer: It need not be.)

Comment: @zhw. Why doesn't it follow? If there is no such sequence, then for all sequences converging to b in (a,b), the limit of their derivative sequence is finite. Is this not true?

Comment: Well the limit of the derivative sequence might not exist. More importantly, all you can deduce is that $f'$ is bounded **above** in some interval $(a',b).$